# upload a file via APIConnect

Tags: file, file-upload, upload, apiconnect

We are using APIConnect as a gateway for all our API.

We have a REST service that accepts a byte array (from a file upload form) and save the file on the backend.

When proxed via APIConnect, I get the following error, with status code 500. How I can fix it?

```
{
 "httpCode":"500",
 "httpMessage":"Internal Server Error",
 "moreInformation":"JSON type length exceeded"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error looks like it comes from the Datapower JSON parser limits.  Is the file large?  If you can access the Datapower you can change these limits.

Answer (score 1):

As David Shute explained above this error seems to be due to the **JSON parser limits** defined in DataPower. You can see that the default values in the following documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y_7.2.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/json_parserlimits.html

I believe I found a similar question posted with some suggestions on how to fix the problem though:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/324780/json-type-length-exceeded-1.html

I would suggest looking at the answers provided there to see if they solve your issue.